# Android scrollable Tabbar

Tags: android, tabs, tabbar

is it somehow possible to have horizontal scrollable tabbar if there are more than e.g. 10 tabs in it?

Have anybody implemented something like this?

[image]

Mur

Ps.
It was not nice, what I did: I've deleted almost the same topic, I'd started yesterday. A big SORRY for man, who answered it already, even if it wasn't really the answer I'm looking for.

Answer (score 0):

There actually is a way to implement this and it is called swipeable tabs layout. I have managed to use it in one of the apps I developed and published on Google Play. Here is the code to implement it:

SectionPagerAdapter class:

```
public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

        public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            Fragment fragment = new Fragment();
            switch (position) {
            case 0:
                return fragment = new HomeFragment();
            case 1:
                return fragment = new EventFragment();
            case 2:
                return fragment = new CoreTeamFragment();
            case 3:
                return fragment = new MapsFragment();
            case 4:
                return fragment = new FacebookFragment();
            default:
                break;
            }
            return fragment;
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            // Show 5 total pages.
            return 5;
        }

        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
            Locale l = Locale.getDefault();
            switch (position) {
            case 0:
                return getString(R.string.title_section1).toUpperCase(l);
            case 1:
                return getString(R.string.title_section2).toUpperCase(l);
            case 2:
                return getString(R.string.title_section3).toUpperCase(l);
            case 3:
                return getString(R.string.title_section4).toUpperCase(l);
            case 4:
                return getString(R.string.title_section5).toUpperCase(l);
            }
            return null;
        }
    }
```

Main class

```
public class CentruActivity extends FragmentActivity {

    SectionsPagerAdapter mSectionsPagerAdapter;
    ViewPager mViewPager;
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_centru);

        mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(
                getSupportFragmentManager());
        mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
        mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);

        // getActionBar();
    }

    public ActionBar getActionBar() {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Please consider accepting this answer if it has helped you. Otherwise, we would be more than happy to assist you :)